# How to re-prompt user input after incorrect type of data is given in Python 3.6

Tags: python, loops, input, user-input, python-3.6

This question has not been asked in relation to Python 3.6 .
I need a solution to re-prompt a specific user input question in a series of input questions if data is given as anything else but an integer or float in this case.

Lets say they input the correct float data for the first question, but then lets say that input a string character into the second question. That outputs a "ValueError: could not convert string to float: ".

Is there a way using looping or another method to re-prompt the SECOND input question that they failed to put integer/float data in? Furthermore, can you re-prompt only the second question instead of having to start over and re-prompt to the FIRST question?

```
counter = 0
counter += float(input("What is number 1?"))
counter += float(input("What is number 2?"))
counter += float(input("What is number 3?"))
print(counter)
```

EDIT: I did read the posted articles containing 9 answers which is similar, but non of them dealt with multiple input questions one after another. The provided answered were helpful, but I still don't quite get how to re-prompt the 2nd or 3rd question after an incorrect data type is entered. In summary: I would like the program to re-prompt the question that failed rather than having the user have to begin at question 1.

Comment: The answers to the questions you have found are still valid in python 3.6

Comment: I edited my original question for more clarity.

Comment: The construct used to re-prompt one question can be repeated as many times as you wish for as many questions as you wish. You need to have the question inside a `while` loop, and a `try`/`except` inside that loop wrapping the `input`, and some way to break out of the `while` loop when a correct answer is inputted. 100% of what you need is in the duplicate, you just need to extrapolate it to your single use case. In other words, don't have all the `input`s in a single `while` block and you're set.

Comment: Put the retry-for-a-single-input functionality into a function and just call it multiple time.

Comment: Ok ill give it a try. I have already used while loops with a try / except. I was having an issue breaking out of the loop and continuing the program. Thank you for everybody's help. Ill see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

Something like this pseudo-code would work:

```
for q in questions:
    while True:
        ask_question
        if question_result_validated:
            break
```